# Linux block outgoing traffic to a specific ip without iptables

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, docker

I basically need to run the following `iptables -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.169.254 -j DROP` except I cannot use `iptables` because the program is running in a docker container and I cannot use the `--privileged` argument (shared platform).

Is there an alternative to iptables that I could use to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 7):

You might want to add a null route for that specific ip address.  Although, this makes ALL communication to the address impossible, this accomplishes what you need.

You can find examples online of this.  one of them. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-drop-or-block-attackers-ip-with-null-routes.html

Something like this

```
route add -host IP-ADDRESS reject
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use the ip command to do the same thing, but check the man page for ip as you have a lot of options on _how_ you want to block that address.  Example where you want to silently discard the packets:  ip route add blackhole 169.254.169.254

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting similar errors using `route` and `ip`: "route: ioctl 0x890b failed: Operation not permitted" and "ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted" which seems to have the same cause, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708376/why-am-i-getting-an-rtnetlink-operation-not-permitted-when-using-pipework-with-d

Answer (score 0):

Docker, by the very definition of a container, is isolating you from the host environment. Anything that lets you do this from within the container without exposing the host via `--privileged` or some remote api interface should be a security exploit of the container.

Comment: Sure I know that, and I'm not trying to change anything on the host, I just want to block the traffic within the container so I am looking at a different way to achieve this result at a higher layer.